# Regex that match words and words with apostrophes

Tags: java, regex

Sorry if this is a duplicate post. I have a method that is supposed to parse all the words in a file. A word should only consist of letters `a-z` and an apostrophe. Here's my code snippet:

```
public void loadInput(File fileName) throws IOException {
        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileName);
            int numWords = 0;
            while(sc.hasNext("[A-Za-z\']+")) {
                String word = sc.next().toLowerCase(); // case-insenstive
                numWords++;
                System.out.println(word);
            }
            System.out.println("Total words in text file: " + numWords);
            sc.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error has occured");
        }

    }
```

As an example input:

```
alice's conversations in it, `and what is the use of a book,'
thought alice `without pictures or conversation?'
```

It should match all the words including `alice's` but not `'without` (it should match only the word `without`)

Comment: You can try `"\\p{L}+(?:'\\p{L}+)?"` or `"\\p{L}+(?:'\\p{L}+)*"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a [negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

`(?<!')[\w']+`, find `[\w']+` not preceed by a `'`.

See https://regex101.com/r/ZfyerX/3